# Standard way of connecting signal and slot within Qt

Tags: qt, qt5, signals-slots

I've just been developing application in QtCreator with Qt5 for a short amount of time, and have just learned how to connect a signal with a slot. From what I understood, there are a few ways:

1. Using the connect() method:

Using connect() method provided by QObject class :

```
connect(
sender, SIGNAL( valueChanged( QString, QString ) ),
receiver, SLOT( updateValue( QString ) )
);
```

Or with Qt5:

```
connect(
sender, &Sender::valueChanged,
receiver, &Receiver::updateValue
);
```

2. Clicking a widget in "Design" window, choosing "Go to slot..." and a function will be created. For example, choosing signal `Clicked()` will generate the following code:

   `void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() { }`
3. Using "Edit Signal/Slot" mode directly in the "Design" window.

So my questions are:

1. What's the standard way of connecting signals and slots?
2. What's the point of other method? And when do we use those?

Sources: [Qt connect method](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)

Comment: Full answer: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: @eyllanesc so I should always use connect()? What's the other method for?

Comment: You can also use the implicit connection as shown in `on_pushButton_clicked`(See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName), but I recommend using the explicit connection with the new syntax as it is less susceptible to bugs since it is verified if the connection is valid at compilation time.

Comment: @eyllanesc so... is the third method recommended/used? The "Using "Edit Signal/Slot" mode directly in the "Design" window." method?

Comment: The third method uses the old syntax so you know my opinion.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks a lot for your clarifications. Have a great day!